# Clearcase on windows 7 can not create dynamic view

Tags: version-control, clearcase

My Clearcase Version: `7.1.0` .

My os is windows 7, after I installed Clearcase. I couldn't create a dynamic view by using Create View.And I found that when i start clearcase service from control panel, there is only two service.

Is there any ways to correct this problem except to download a higher version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClearCase 7.1.2 is deployed on our Windows 7 at work.

However, when I see that there is only two services, that means MVFS (which is a device, not a driver) has failed to install properly.

The usual fix is to uninstall and reinstall ClearCase.
But there is no guarantee for 7.1.0.

---

The OP adds:

> I have reinstall it three times, but the problem still exists

That confirms 7.1.0 is not supported (at least for the dynamic views part) on Windows 7.
As "[System Requirements for ClearCase 7.1.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974)" confirms, Windows7 SP1 actually needs 7.1.2.3 at minimum.
And even then, you can have some issue: " [PM54437: Windows 7 64bit MVFS clients flood albd_server of the View Server host with ALBD_FIND_SERVER RPCs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM54437)" (which needs 7.1.2.6)

So getting the latest 7.1.x is recommended.

---

In your case though, since it isn't possible to get a version above 7.1.0, you can try and install a [Virtual PC Windows Xp](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) on your Windows 7.

> Microsoft Virtual PC for Windows (formerly Connectix Virtual PC) is a client based software virtualization application that allows simultaneous operating systems to run on a single PC.
>   Each virtual machine emulates a complete hardware system—from processor to network card—in a self-contained, isolated software environment, enabling the simultaneous operation of otherwise incompatible systems.

[ClearCase does support Virtual PC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21228619).

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I have reinstall it three times, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @Tony so 7.1.0 is not supported, then. W7 Sp1 actually need 7.1.2.3: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21302974

Comment: @Tony I have edited my answer to propose the only alternative I can think of. If that isn't possible... then you won't have dynamic views with only a 7.1.0 on Windows 7.